# How to query another collection on callback of first query.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a few mongoose schema's defined.

```
var partSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  system: String,
  team: Array,
  quantity: Number, 
});
var part = mongoose.model('part', partSchema);

var peopleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String, 
  pass: String, 
  role: String,
  parts: Array
});

var people = mongoose.model('people', peopleSchema);
```

And I want to send queries based on these schemas, and more, to the user. As such...

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   people.find(function(err, persons){
     if (err) return handleError(err);
     console.log(persons);
     parts.find(function(err, things){
       res.render('in', { user: req.session.user, people:persons, parts:things });
     });
   });
});
```

To remain asynchronous, I would have to nest these calls, right? And I cant nest these calls, because "parts" is no longer defined. I'm wondering if I could do this, and how would I do it? Sorry if it's a noob question, but I've looked this up for days, and haven't seemed to find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable name of your `'part'` model is `part`, not `parts`.  So it should be:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   people.find(function(err, persons){
     if (err) return handleError(err);
     console.log(persons);
     part.find(function(err, things){   // <-- Changed on this line
       res.render('in', {user: req.session.user, people:persons, parts:things});
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that. I feel pretty bad now. Thank you so much!